# parsing pasted text in console application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application, c#-3.0

I have a console application made of C#

it allows user to paste some text as following

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

i know console.readline() wont take it, so I used console.in.readtoend()

```
            string input = Console.In.ReadToEnd(); 

            List<string> inputlist = input.Split('\n').ToList();
```

I need it to parse input text line by line
the above code works, but after pasting, in order to conintue, user has to hit enter once, then hit ctrl+z then hit enter again.

im wondering if there is better way to do it
something that requires just hit enter key once

any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In console if you paste a block of lines they are not executed immediately. That is if you paste

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

nothing happens. Once you hit enter, Read method starts doing it's job. And ReadLine() returns after every new line. So the way I always do it, and IMO it's the easiest way:

```cs
var lines = new List<string>();
string? line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Either you do here something with each line separately or
    lines.Add(line);
}
// You do something with all of the lines
```

Comment: hi this actually worked, just tried again! thank you and congrats for your first accepted answer!! lol

Answer (score 1):

I understand now why the question was hard. Does this work for you?

```
Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+c to end input");
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate
{
    // Eat this event so the program doesn't end
};

int c = Console.Read();
while (c != -1)
{
    s.Append((char)c);
    c = Console.Read();
}

string[] results = s.ToString().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: no, this will not do, cuz it will run after first line and ignore the rest lines

Comment: Changed my original answer (which definitely didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do anything extra. just read by ReadLine and then hit enter.

```
string line1 = Console.ReadLine(); //aaaaa
string line2 = Console.ReadLine(); //bbbbb
string line3 = Console.ReadLine(); //ccccc
```

Comment: well, the problem is, the number of lines is random....thats why i used console.in.readtoend

Comment: It gives you line by line only

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve your issue through the below code.
You just need to press enter once you have pasted all your text .

```
    Console.WriteLine("enter line");
    String s;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        sb.Append(s).Append("\r\n");
    } while (s != "");
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
```